# How do I create a revision of a deregistered/inactive task definition in AWS ECS through AWS CLI command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, ecs-taskdefinition

I need to bring back a deregistered / inactive task definition in ECS by creating a revision of the inactive task definition. I can do this manually through the AWS ECS console. How can this be done by using AWS CLI command line ?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean? Maybe how some screenshots of console that can help?

Comment: @Marcin I mean to say when I deregister a task definition (Say, TaskDefinition1), it goes into INACTIVE state. Now there's no direct way to bring back the same INACTIVE TaskDefinition1 back to ACTIVE state but what I can do instead is create a revision of the INACTIVE TaskDefinition1. I can view the 'Create revision' option inside TaskDefinition1 on the AWS console. How can I achieve the same from AWS CLI ? Meaning is there any aws ecs command that can help me create a revision from an INACTIVE task definition (TaskDefinition1 in this case) ?

Comment: Long story short, I do not want to create a revision from the INACTIVE Task Definition manually from the console. I want to automate the same by running an AWS ECS command through a script.  Is there any command that can help me with the same ?